# what is the correct way to get ownership of an argument with clap?

Tags: rust, clap

I would like to pass the options of my CLI program via a `Config`-struct that has ownership of its values, i.e. `String`s of paths. The now deprecated `ArgMatches::values_of_lossy()` returned an owned `String`, however, `ArgMatches::get_many()` only returns a `ValuesRef<>`. What is the best way to get ownership of the argument itself, ideally without cloning?

Comment: [`ArgMatches::remove_many`](https://docs.rs/clap/latest/clap/struct.ArgMatches.html#method.remove_many) will give you ownership, by moving those values out of the `ArgMatches` struct.

Comment: You may want to consider using the [`derive` feature](https://docs.rs/clap/latest/clap/_derive/index.html) if you have a struct you want to parse into.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`ArgMatches::remove_many`](https://docs.rs/clap/latest/clap/struct.ArgMatches.html#method.remove_many) will give you ownership, by moving those values out of the `ArgMatches` struct.